# How to collect the earnings in the software center

Tags: software-center

Does anyone know what process should I follow in order to collect the earnings from the sales of software published in the Software Center? Is there any restriction related to the minimum amount to be collected by those earnings?

<sub>[Original question in Spanish](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/313441/1)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The [**Commercial software FAQ's**](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/commercial-software-faqs/) clearly states the next in the "Payment" section:

### How do I get paid for the sales of my application?

> Currently, we pay all publishers on a quarterly basis. Following
>   publishing of your application we’ll contact you for confirmation of
>   your invoice details. We’ll then pay you electronically, via PayPal,
>   each quarter. In the future we’ll introduce monthly automated payment.

### How will I receive my money?

> You’ll receive an invoice and your payments on a quarterly basis. We
>   pay the publisher either by electronic bank transfer or through
>   PayPal. For Paypal payments we’ll pay the registered address that’s
>   associated with your account in the Developer Portal.

You must have in consideration that the "Selling software and content" section also states this:

### What is the transaction fee?

> The application publisher chooses a global price to sell their
>   application for. For each sale Canonical retains a transaction fee of
>   20% after tax. If you sell an application for 10.00 USD, then the fee
>   will be 2.00 USD. Please note that credit card chargebacks are
>   excluded and will be charged additionally to the developers account.

If you need further information or if you are in the need to contact them I thinkg it is a great idea to login in the **[Ubuntu App Developer](http://developer.ubuntu.com/)** site in order to get some kind of support over there.

Don't forget to fully read all the FAQ's, maybe the answer to your other questions is already considered right there.

Good luck!